# In Android DataBinding how to get integer from editText and use it in by Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I want to use DataBinding in Android by Kotlin with below example
I have two EditText with one button  and two TextViews below them, whenever i click button i expected the texts that i have entered in EditTexts will be shown in two TextViews.
I have User Class (Model) and if two fields of this class be String every thing is OK and my code work normally but My problem is when one field be integer i got this error :
cannot find symbol import com.example.mydatabinding.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;

it's appreciated if some Body could help me .

My xml code:

[image]

sorry this platform is not User friendly for me  at all i can't use Ctrl K for all of XML code !! so i bring some in photo some by ctrl K every time for asking question i got bad headache !
let's continue

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_name_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="name ?"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_age_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="age ?"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_name_edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apply_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_age_edit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@={myUser.name}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/apply_btn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_age_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@={myUser.age}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_name_text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
</layout>
```

and user class code :

```
data class User (var name : String ="" , var age :Int =0) {
```

}

and MainActivity code :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your textView you are using `android:text="@={myUser.age}"` which is causing problem because your `myUser.age` is `integer` and you cannot set `integer` value in your textView.

Change :-

`"@={myUser.age}"` to

`@={Integer.toString(myUser.age)}`

and the problem will be sorted.

Comment: can you please post your log here ?

Comment: also please have a look in your main activity code :-
`myUser?.age = userAgeText.text,toString().toInt()` shouldn't it be  `user_age_edit` there ?

Comment: also i changed @={} to @{} to work , and if i  don't it doesn't work